# ASP.NET MVC 4: Handle exception caused by JsonValueProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I have an action that is called using requests with `application/json`in the Content-type header. These requests will automatically create a JsonValueProvider that tries to deserialize the request's content. When the json is malformed, the value provider will throw an exception leading to the application's error page.

To reproduce this behavior, simply POST invalid json data to an action sending `application/json` as the Content-type header. This will trigger the exception.

**[Edit]**

Not much code is needed. Simply create an empty controller method and use a tool like Firefox "Poster" to send an invalid request to the action.

```
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.Json(true);
    }
}
```

Then use Poster:

- Set Content-type to `application/json`
- Set Request content to `{"This is invalid JSON:,}`
- Send the request

The result will be the full-blown standard ASP.NET HTML error page (either generic or custom, depending on your application).

**[/Edit]**

Since my action is called by embedded devices, I would like to send short responses, instead of the HTML error page. I would like to be able to create a response with status code 500, Content-type: `text/plain`, and the exception's message as it's content.

I have already tried a custom model binder and a custom error handler attribute but neither are called since the exception occurs earlier on in the processing pipeline. Is there a way to handle this error?

As a workaround, I have currently disabled the JsonValueProvider for the whole application and load the values from the request body myself. If there is a way to disable the JsonValueProvider on a per action basis, this would also help.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Could you post some samples from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the Application_Error event in your Global.asax and handle the exception as you want:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Write("An error occured while processing your request. Details: " + exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a valid option, but is then not limited to specific actions. The application consists of both a real web application, as well as an API part for the embedded devices. The general exception page should be in place. I only want it customized for specific MVC actions.

Comment: Sure, it's pretty trivial to test which is the current controller and action in the exception handler. Once you know that you could perform the exception handling only for those requests.

Comment: Is it really so trivial? In the Error event handler, I do not have the MVC RouteValues, or do I? I do NOT want to make this dependent on the URL, since the routes are subject to change, and I don't want to always have to remember to adapt the pattern matching in the global error handler.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely trivial to get the RouteData from the current context: `var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));`. And then just ask for the current controller: `routeData.GetRequiredString("controller")`. Or the current action if you will: `routeData.GetRequiredString("action")`.

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you! I have marked your answer as accepted.I would still like to know, whether it is possible to disable the JsonValueProvider on a per method basis, since it throws a relatively generic exception (I believe the InvalidOperationException), that might also occur on different operations and might require different handling.